# "Data" American pronunciation

Tags: pronunciation

I would like to know what the states where **data** is pronounced like "Dayta" are or what's this accent called?

Also, where is it pronounced normally like "daata"? and what's the name of the accent?

Comment: I don't think this pronunciation is unique to American accents.  I think it's more personal preference.  Some people say *dayta* and some people say *dahta*.  [There's even an old song about it.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zZ3fjQa5Hls)

Comment: The full OED lists ***four*** pronunciations (Brit.ˈ/deɪtə/, /dɑːtə/, U.S. /dædə/, /deɪdə/) - essentially two British and two American versions of the vowel difference noted by OP here, so as @Andrew says, it's not even "regional" enough to talk about a US/UK split here. Not so much a matter of "accent" as just two variations that people everywhere might choose between.

Comment: The pronunciation of **data** isn't particularly regional because it's not an everyday word that people might pick up from their environment as small children.  You do find regional pronunciations in everyday words that children learn from their parents or peer groups, but for more specialized or technical words that people learn later in life, pronunciation is going to be more idiosyncratic than regional.

Comment: Earlier at EL&U: *[Data pronunciation: “dayta” or “dahta”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10155/)*.

Comment: It probably depends on how much Star Trek [NG] they've watched too. Even the very British JL Picard called him 'dayta'.

Comment: In my neck of the woods 'dahta' is slightly more common than 'dayta', but there is not much between them.

Comment: @Canadian Yankee, you have a good point. As a matter of fact I remember learning the word "data" from my dad when I was very young, and even trying to apply it incorrectly. I pronounced it /dædə/ then, but I'd tend toward /deɪdə/ these days.